# RecyclerView animation not working in GingerBread

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I am using `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());` for animation while adding and removing a row of `RecycerView`.

It is working perfectly on `Kitkat`  but not in `GingerBread`

**MainActivity.java**

```
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter=new MyRecyclerView(createMockList(),this,1);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        setlistener(adapter);
```

I tried to set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` and

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8"
```

in my menifest file but no luck.

Please help

Comment: FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED is introduced in Honeycomb. :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski then any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, default item animator support JellyBean+ because it is using the new animation system.